# If choose more than one, the price increases

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a project. My codes are simply written below

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="A" value="A">A
<input type="checkbox" name="B" value="B">B
<input type="checkbox" name="C" value="C">C
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$price=0;
  if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
  //the code goes here
  }
?>
```

If only one of the option is chosen, it's free (no price). But, if the user chooses more than one, the `$price` is +10 in every option. So, it can be illustrated like this

- Choose 1 = free
- Choose 2 = +10
- Choose 3 = +20

I have no idea with my PHP and the line `//the code goes here` is still empty. Any idea?

Comment: use concatenation for this and check if the selected box is empty or not and then put your logic

Comment: What do you mean by "the line `//the code goes here` is still empty"? That *is* an empty line - `//` denotes a comment.

Comment: This looks like a homework or quiz question.   Why don't you give it an attempt first?

Answer (score 0):

Homework, huh? I didn't even have to go to college for that one.

```
<?php

if( isset($_POST) )
{
  $count = 0;
  $arr = [
    array_key_exists('A', $_POST),
    array_key_exists('B', $_POST),
    array_key_exists('C', $_POST)
  ];

  for( $i = 0; $i < 3; $i++ ) {
    if( $arr[$i] ) $count++;
  }
  // Now count the total - 1 and * it by 10
  if( $count > 1 ) $total = ($count - 1) * 10;
}
```

Basically this script will check for the key in the `$_POST` array, if you do not select a `checkbox` it would not create the key for `_POST` array and thus it would be false.

If it's false then just skip by default. However, if it's `true`, it will increment to the `$count` variable. Then if `$count` is greater than one than we add create a new variable of `$total = $count - 1`. That will remove one value from `$count` then times it by 10.